# Align unique values in two columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
COL 1  COL 2
 A      E
 B      G 
 C      A
 G      A
 D      C
 E      F
 D      F
 F      F
```

I want it to look like:

```
COL 1  COL 2
 A      A
 BLANK  A
 B      BLANK
 C      C
 D      BLANK
 D      BLANK
 E      E
 F      F
 BLANK  F
 BLANK  F
 G      G
```

Please help me out. I have tons of numbers in two columns and want to align them as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to reorganize the sample data you provided correctly.

```
Sub mcr_fix()
    Dim rw As Long, c As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        For c = 1 To 2
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(c)
                .Cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            End With
        Next c
        rw = 3
        Do While CBool(Application.CountA(.Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 2)))
            If .Cells(rw, 1).Value > .Cells(rw, 2).Value Then
                .Cells(rw, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            ElseIf .Cells(rw, 1).Value < .Cells(rw, 2).Value Then
                .Cells(rw, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
            rw = rw + 1
            If rw > 500 Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing something similar. Nice work!

Comment: Probably want to include how to use it

Comment: @Pathfinder - I actually left my check-out-of-infinite-loop code line in when I copied and pasted after testing. I was just returning to advise the OP about it.

Comment: @AbeikuAcquah - after checking to make it it runs on a smaller sample you need to remove `If rw > 500 Then Exit Do` to run on *tons of numbers*.

Comment: wow. thats magnificent.thanks soo soo much. soo soo happy but i had a slight change from what the output should be. A2 should be blank but its B and A3 should have been B. Please resolve that for me. thankx

Comment: I think i have found the solution. i created two additional rows which i didnt need. so after applying the macro, i take them out. Mr Jeep, tons of thanks to u

Comment: Please. assuming there are 6 columns, we are comparing the first three columns with the last three columns. The headings of the first three are DATE, NARRATION and AMOUNT. The headings of the last three too are DATE, NARRATION and AMOUNT. so when shifting, based on the AMOUNT, the DATE, NARRATION and AMOUNT of the first three columns should move simultaneously and likewise the last three columns but it should follow the prescription above

Comment: @AbeikuAcquah - perhaps you should edit your original question to show *relevant* data and an *accurate* description of what you actually require. Post any work you've done yourself on the issue of converting what I've supplied to the *actual* problem.

Comment: @ Jeeped - Okay will definitely do that. Thanks